# TabControl TabIndexChanged won't fire

Tags: winforms

The [TabIndexChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event of the Windows Forms [TabControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't fire when I change between tabs. But the [SelectedIndexChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event is fired.

What is the explanation for this?

Answer (score 14):

The `TabIndexChanged` event fires when you change the `TabIndex` property of the control-- the order of controls related to the parent form, etc.  It has nothing to do with when the user is switching tabs.

Besides the `SelectedIndexChanged` event, you probably want to explore the `Selected, Selecting, Deselected, and Deselecting` events to determine what to do when the user is changing tabs.

Comment: Thank you for this. It's a lifesaver!